# How to set environment variables for Django settings.py with Jenkins

Tags: python, django, jenkins, deployment, environment-variables

I have a `settings.py` file for my Django project that reads in environment variables for some fields. This works great for local development. I'm not sure of how to make this work for my Jenkins build (Freestyle project). An extra layer of complexity is that some of these variables contain sensitive data (passwords, etc.) and so need to be secured.

So far, I have been able to use [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/) to set up a secret `.env` file and can successfully access that as an environment variable.

1. How do I go about setting all the 'actual' variables from that file? Or is this bad practice?
2. If it's not bad, wouldn't those variables continue living on the server after the build has finished?
3. If it is bad, what is the better way to do this? I can update the `settings.py` file easily enough if needed to make this work.
4. Maybe using something like [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) is the right approach?